# Why is .[expression] invalid XPath syntax

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

This syntax in a XLST template:

```
.[starts-with(@type,'&amp;#x')]
```

gives the following error message when using Xalan:

```
XPath error: Use 'self::node()[predicate]' instead of '.[predicate]'.
```

The XPath 1.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is unclear on this point, but it appears that you can't use the abbreviated node syntax in front of a predicate?

Can anyone confirm this or point to specific syntax rules governing precisely what can appear just before a predicate?

Comment: Please provide the complete XSLT context of the use of this XPath... I might help to analyse the problem

Comment: Let us know if JLRishe's post answers your question.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question:  Thanks!